# Twilio: RestAPI for SMS returns status "WaitingForActivation"

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api, two-factor-authentication

I am using Twilio Rest-Api for sending SMS from my Controller class and it returns : Id = 166, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

```
 public Task SendSmsAsync(string number, string message)
    {

        var accountSid = Options.SMSAccountIdentification;
        var authToken = Options.SMSAccountPassword;

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        return MessageResource.CreateAsync(
          to: new PhoneNumber(number),
          from: new PhoneNumber(Options.SMSAccountFrom),
          body: message);
    }
```

I am calling this method from Controller class :

```
var result =  _smsSender.SendSmsAsync("+92331234566", "Hi its my first msg to ya. Twilio")
```

It is returning status: waitingForActivation.

Will this be resolved if I make the whole process asynchronous ?? though I have tried it but somehow I am not reaching the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are using an async method so the result is going to be a task that hasn't resolved yet. I'm not a C# developer, but I believe you need the `async` and `await` keywords in the right place. Something like:

```
public async Task SendSmsAsync(string number, string message)
{

    var accountSid = Options.SMSAccountIdentification;
    var authToken = Options.SMSAccountPassword;

    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    return await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
      to: new PhoneNumber(number),
      from: new PhoneNumber(Options.SMSAccountFrom),
      body: message);
}
```

Check out this [blog post for a good example](https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/03/02/twilio-with-net-core/) too.

Comment: I have already tried many solutions, also the one you have mentioned. Now, I am getting this error: `'Permission to send an SMS has not been enabled for the region indicated by the 'To' number: +92xxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Ah, for that you need to go to [SMS geo permissions](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions) in the Twilio console and make sure you have the countries you are sending to checked.